# How can I test returned date and time format in postman

Tags: api, postman

I need to make sure that the returned date and time format in the API response is correct .

Let's say the STANDARD format I want to apply  is DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS and the returned value from the API is MM/YY HH:MM , how can I make sure that this value is incorrect ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please read about [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). When asking questions you should always include the code you've tried so far.

Comment: What does the response structure look like? You can write checks against the value to ensure its coming back with the correct format etc. We would need more information though.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to tweak the regex and set `dateToTest` from the response you get.

```
let dateToTest = // set based on your response

pm.test("Correct date format", function () {
    let regEx = new RegExp("\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}");

    pm.expect(regEx.test(dateToTest).to.eq(true);
});
```